# Python: Fast computation of the average value using trapezoid rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

Using Python, I have to process some data.

I am given the values of approximately 50 functions at approximately 10 million time points. These values are given as a 2D-list `matrix`, i.e., `matrix[i]` is a list of values

`[t_i, value of f1 at t_i, value of f2 at t_i ..., value of fN of t_i]`

where `N = 50`.

Due to

- the probable noise in the data (the functions are some measurements)
- non-equidistant time points (sometimes, the time step is a few seconds, but sometimes it can be measured in days)

I decided to work with the values that are averages of the given values on some predefined time intervals of a fixed length.

I have tried different lengths of the intervals: they range between one minute and one hour.

My algorithm for computing the averages works as follows:

```
matrix = ...  # read matrix
t0 = matrix[0][0]
ts_new = [t0 + i * time_step for i in range(some_bound)]
buckets = [[] for t in ts_new]
for i, instance in enumerate(matrix):
    t_i = instance[0]
    put i to the bucket with index j, such that ts_new[j] <= t_i < ts_new[j + 1] 
for bucket in buckets:
    compute the average values of f1, ... , fN over the instances from bucket
```

> The bottle-neck of the algorithm is the last for-loop.

If I convert `matrix` into `numpy.array` and compute the mean values of a `bucket` as `matrix[bucket, :].mean(axis=0)`, **this works pretty fast**, but the computed values **don't make much sense**:

If the values of `f1` at times `ts = [0, 99, 100]` are respectively `ys = [0, 0, 2]`, the mean function returns `2/3` (as expected). However, the average value of `f1` should be much closer to `0`. Using the trapezoid rule, one would obtain the average value of `0.01`, which makes more sense.

So, currently, I am using

- the `scipy.integrate.trapz` method for computing the average of a bucket: the area of trapezoids is divided by the interval length
- the `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` method to get the values of functions `f` at the interval borders, e.g., I use the last point in the previous bucket and the first point in the given bucket, to compute the value at the start of the corresponding time interval (similarly for the end of the time interval)

The second bullet is needed since a minute time interval length is so short that only 1 or two points are sometimes in the bucket. The procedure goes like this:

```
# for one bucket
means = [0 for col in range(N)]
for col in range(1, N + 1):  # for each function f
    xs = []
    ys = []
    if can_interpolate_at_start:
        f_lin = scipy.interpolate.interp1d([tPrevLast, tNowFirst], [yPrevLast, yNowFirst])
        xs.append(t_bucketStart)
        ys.append(f_lin(t_bucketStart))
    xs += matrix[bucket, 0]
    ys += matrix[bucket, col]
    if can_interpolate_at_end:
        # ...
    means[col - 1] = scipy.integrate.trapz(ys, xs) / (xs[-1] - xs[0])
```

The values of `can_interpolate_at_start` and `can_interpolate_at_end` depend only on time gaps (but special care must be taken for the first and the last bucket ...): I do not use the interpolated points if the time difference between, e.g., the last point in the previous bucket and the current bucket is too big.

> My problem: the current approach is **really slow** (two hours or so for one-minute time intervals). How can I make it faster?

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  First of all, where is the slow code?

Comment: If you take the area of one trapezoid and divide it by the interval length... aren't you just getting the average of the two function values? (maybe I'm not following something). Here is something simple you can do (if you want I can post an implementation): given one function, for every pair of time stamps, take the average between the function values at both points and multiply it by the difference between the time stamps. Sum for every pair of time stamps and then divide by the difference between the first and last time stamp.

Comment: @Prune a) I cannot give you the data. Does the ful `compute_mean` function suffice?  b) As I mentioned, the slow part is the last of loop, i.e., the computation of the averages.

Comment: @jdehesa You are right. I did not actually tried to implement it myself, since I assumed that their implementation should be somehow optimized ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple thing you can do is, thinking in terms of intervals, take the average of each function for each interval and multiply if by the interval length, then divide by the total time:

```
import numpy as np

matrix = ...
data = np.asarray(matrix)
t_diff = np.diff(data[:, 0])
means_sum = np.sum(t_diff[:, np.newaxis] * (data[:-1, 1:] + data[1:, 1:]) / 2, axis=0)
means = means_sum / (data[-1, 0] - data[0, 0])
```

Comment: This actually seems great:) I will also try to get rid of scipy ... Will report the results.